# Structure of a scheme on $\operatorname{Proj} A$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, projective-schemes

Let $A$ be $\mathbb Z_{\geq 0}$ graded commutative ring. Now, in almost every resource I read, we define the structure a scheme on $\operatorname{Proj} A$, by taking the distinguished basis $D_+(f)$ of $\operatorname{Proj}A$, identifying $D_+(f)$ with $\operatorname{Spec}(A_f)_0$ and gluing the sheafs $\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}(A_f)_0}$ together along the intersections. This makes sense to me, but why don't we just emulate the construction of the structure sheaf on $\operatorname{Spec}A$?

More precisely, let $\psi_f:\operatorname{Spec(A_f)_0}\rightarrow D_+(f)$ be the homemorphisms, and define a (pre)-sheaf on thee basis of distinguished opens by $D_+(f)\mapsto \mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec(A_f)_0}}(\psi_f^{-1}(U_f))=(A_f)_0$. Why don't we just show this is a sheaf on the base of distinguished opens, and then define the structure sheaf on $\operatorname{Proj}A$ to be this sheaf?

I feel like these constructions should be equivalent, and I also feel like that the latter would be computationally less intensive, since we have already done the hard work of proving this is a sheaf on the base in the affine case? Maybe I am missing something though.

Comment: *Bosch, Algebraic Geometry
and Commutative Algebra* does such construction.

Comment: When defining $\mathsf{Spec}$, you are merely defining a locally ringed space. When defining $\mathsf{Proj}$, you are defining a scheme. It may seem more straightforward to do the analogous construction (of the locally ringed space), but then you would still have to prove that what you get has an affine open cover. Isn't this procedure not more or less equivalent in complexity to the other construction where the affine open cover comes for free?

Comment: @Acrobatic thank you will check that out.